# transform.Rotate needs to change axis of rotation

Tags: unity, c#

So I'm making a game in Unity. After many failed attemps from either being bored of the idea, or something going wrong and me giving up I think (hope) that will be the good one.

I have made a simple racing game with a track and a car. I am using transform.Translate to move it, but when I use transform.Rotate to turn it goes around the x axis. How do I change the axis it goes around? I cant find anything online.

```
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * handling);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * handling);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter you pass to `transform.Rotate` is a a vector with 3 elements. The 3 elements say how far to rotate around the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis. `Vector3.right` and `Vector3.left` are shorthands for `Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` and `Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`. These are rotations around the x-axis.

When you want to turn an object around the z-axis, for example, you would use:

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * handling * Time.deltaTime);
```

which can be abbreviated as

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * handling * Time.deltaTime);
```

When you use vectors for rotation instead of translation, the names of the constants defined in Vector3 are a bit misleading. So I would recommend you to either write out all three components as in my first example, or define your own constants like this:

```
static class RotationVector {
    static readonly Vector3 rollLeft = Vector3.forward;
    static readonly Vector3 rollRight = Vector3.backward;
    static readonly Vector3 yawRight = Vector3.up;
    static readonly Vector3 yawLeft = Vector3.down;
    static readonly Vector3 pitchDown = Vector3.left;
    static readonly Vector3 pitchUp = Vector3.right;
}
```

Note: these assignments assume that in your game x-axis means "forward" and the y-axis means "up" (like the Vector3 constants assume). They are different depending on which axis represents which direction in your game (in 2d-games seen from the bird-eye perspective, many people use y as the north-south axis and z as the up-down axis).

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out finally. I use forward and back as the rotation direction. I was literally just rolling through vector options to find it though. Pure luck.

Comment: When you want to gain a deeper understanding of Unity you need to know not just *how* it works but rather *why* it works. I hope my answer is able to provide you with more insight.